# "watch" command doesn't work on alias

Tags: 20.04, alias, watch-command

`watch` command doesn't work for alias commands.

Without alias:

```
➜  scrcpy git:(master) git -P branch
* master
➜  scrcpy git:(master) watch git branch
```

[image]

With alias

```
➜  scrcpy git:(master) which gb
gb: aliased to git branch
➜  scrcpy git:(master) watch gb
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to alias `watch` as well for this to work.  It needs space around the command, i.e. `alias watch='watch '` and after the space it is expecting the next part to be an alias as well.

So, we will create an alias with the `-n` in it as well.  Since you are doing every 2 seconds create a new alias to watch every 2 seconds.

```
alias watch-2='watch -n 2 '
```

Then you would just run it as

```
watch-2 gb
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Have you got any idea just to set aias as `watch` so that any built-in arguments like `-n` can be passed dynamically? e.g `watch -n4 gb`

Comment: @RajeshChaudhary Unfortunately, it doesn't work that way.  To watch an alias you have to have an alias of it. So, for 4 seconds it would be the same here but with 4.  I can't see any other way around it.