# Why doesn't the "watch" command work on an alias?

Tags: users, alias, watch-command

So I've made my customized alias command and tried to use it with `alias`, but my alias was not recognized while concatenated with the `watch` command.

So I tried to make a thread of it and fortunately, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298778/watch-command-doesnt-work-on-alias) one helped me out.

But what is the reason for this?

I've created an alias in my `.bashrc` which works perfectly fine.

```
alias gpu='sensors nouveau-pci-0100'
alias cpu='sensors coretemp-isa-0000'
```

and when I concatenate `watch` and `gpu` like this:

```
watch GPU
```

I get this below every 2 seconds:

```
sh: 1: gpu: not found
```

And I solved it regarding the mentioned thread above like this:

```
alias = watchh='watch '
watchh gpu
```

But why does this happen? Why can' It use my surely defined alias command?

My guess is it is something about the **user** because I've gone root once and I couldn't use my alias but I surely need an expert to answer this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's nothing to do with users.

Aliases are only expanded in the **interactive** shell for which they are defined - so an interactive bash shell if you defined them via `~/.bashrc`, or an interactive zsh shell if you define them in `~/.zshrc` for example.

The `watch` command invokes commands via a **non**-interactive `/bin/sh` shell.

By aliasing `watch` itself, as `alias watchh='watch '` (with a trailing space) and then using `watchh gpu`, you force the current interactive shell to expand `gpu` *before* it's passed to `watch`.

Note that in `zsh`, aliases may be defined as *global* which allows them to be expanded anywhere in a command - avoiding the need to alias `watch` with a trailing space.

Comment: You can name the alias `watch` without the extra `h`. I also do this for `sudo` in my .bashrc.

Answer (score 5):

The `watch` command does not locate aliases, only commands in your search path. As an alternative, define `gpu` and `cpu` as shell scripts instead of aliases and place them in your search path. Then your `watch gpu` and `watch cpu` commands will work fine.

For example, if `$HOME/bin` is a directory in your search path, create a file `$HOME/bin/gpu` containing the line:

```
sensors nouveau-pci-0100
```

Make the file executable:

```
$ chmod +x $HOME/bin/gpu
```

and you're ready to go!

```
$ watch gpu
```

Then do the same for `cpu`.

Comment: That seems legitimate dude but there is no ```/bin``` inside my home directory. if you meant ```~/bin```  by ```$HOME/bin```

Comment: @YoloWex is something stopping you from making one?

Comment: @YoloWex: Yes, `~` expands to `$HOME`, your home directory.  The default .profile scripts on most systems will add that directory to your `$PATH` if it exists.

Comment: @hobbs I tried making one and followed the instructions and it WORKED. Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest `~/.local/bin` instead, for consistency with the [XDG base directory specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html), but it doesn't _really_ matter.